# How do you create a folder using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, shell

I have a SQL script which selects data from DB and stores it to files. I am unable to create a directory to store these files.

I have shell script that loads the SQL file. Shell and the SQL are on separate server than MySQL db. I would prefer to create this directory using SQL as I want to avoid ssh.

Any suggestions? Surprisingly I couldn't find anything on Google.

Comment: Use the shell to create the output directory before running the scripts.

Comment: @TomFenech Shell is on a different server than DB (where the folder will be created)

Comment: Presumably you have some means of accessing the output files (e.g. SSH), in which case, couldn't you just use that to create the directory?

Comment: @TomFenech The folder will get picked up by a different process. I just wanted to know if there are other options than ssh if not I guess I have to ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you're using mysql, according to your tags. You could do it with a Microsoft SQL Server or Oracle database but unfortunately, at the moment, there is no solution to create a directory from MySQL.

Some will guide you with a workaround based on the creation of a data directory, I wouldn't recommand this, as it could lead to performances issues in the future, or worst.

The best solution would be to use a script (java, vbscript, SSH, batch, ...). Again, you won't be able to start this script within your SQL query easily. I know that's no good news, but it is important not to lead you on the wrong direction.

I would suggest to reverse your thinking, and start your SQL query from a script (again, any language you're used to).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any other way other than opening ssh session to the target box.

1. Open ssh session
2. Create directory
3. close ssh session
4. Load sql file using shell
5. The sql adds the generated files to the directory created in step 2.

```
ssh -t $USER@$HOST <<-SSH-END;
  mkdir -p "dir/path";
  exit;
SSH-END
```

Sharing just in case someone else needs to do the same.